# Use matplotlib to graph a csv column and occurrences

Tags: python, csv, matplotlib, plot, graph

I've looked around for sources on how to use matplotlib to create graphs (line, bar, and pie) from a csv file, but they're not exactly what I'm looking for. I am wondering how, from this example file I created below, would I graph just the Favorite Color column along with the number of occurrences of each color?

```
ID     Name       Favorite Color
1      Mary       Blue
2      Bob        Green
3      Simon      Red
4      Lily       Red
5      Gerald     Blue
6      Kathy      Blue
```

Hope that makes sense! Thank you in advance!

Comment: `df.groupby('Favorite Color').size().plot()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to plot this data is probably to use Pandas to load the file into a dataframe, then get the occurrences of each color using [`value_counts`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) and plot the results.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv')
df['Favorite Color'].value_counts().plot.bar()
```